# My initials are MC

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry, limerick

> My initials are M.C. and know me please do;
>   I'm related in essence to many a crew;
>   My syllables count four,
>   Same for vowels I'm sure;
>   Now please decide which are false and are true:
>
> Indeed, I'm known to run...
>   1) alongside a shore.
>   2) alongside a leader.
>   3) on a liquid.
>   4) on a machine.

Three of these are true, and one is false. **Which one?**

*Note: Let's just say for the sake of this problem that "y" is not considered a vowel here.*

**Hint 1:**

> I'm a proper noun that most people have heard of. I'm not a person, though.

Comment: That's quite a Mixed Collection of Motley Clues. It will be a Messy Challenge to figure out the Main Character of this riddle. (If I've written the solution by Mistaken Chance in this Momentary Comment, then Mea Culpa.)

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Not yet, though if you keep going you might! :D

Comment: Welcome to the community, @anodyne!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is...

> ... **MONTE CARLO**.

From the verse:

> "My initials are M.C."... check.
>
>  "I'm related in essence to many a crew"... not sure!  This may be referring to pit crews at Formula 1's [Monte Carlo Rally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_Rally)?
>
>  "My syllables count four"... check.
>
>  "Same for vowels"... check.

As for the statements:

> "I'm known to run alongside a shore."  This is the case for the [location in Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo).
>
>  "I'm known to run on a liquid."  This is the case for the [apparently notable yacht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_(yacht)).
>
>  "I'm known to run on a machine."  This is the case for the [class of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).

It seems, then, that the false statement is...

> "I'm known to run alongside a leader."

Comment: Exactly correct! And thanks for the warm welcome. I was thinking of rot13(Puriebyrg Zbagr Pneyb) for the liquid clue, but that's probably just my American bias. Yours works just as well.

Comment: Oh, I just realized why you thought of that for liquid. Sure, that's one way to interpret "run on". :) I had meant rot13(gur Puriebyrg Zbagr Pneyb orpnhfr vg ehaf ba n yvdhvq shry) for what it's worth.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that when I saw your response... both valid!